# php artisan storage:link creates a storage file

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issue with `php artisan storage:link` when I run it in my terminal, it create a file in my `public/` directory instead of a symlink folder.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you use a docker or WSL terminal. And this is Linux symlink - it looks like a file in windows.

Comment: @Maksim I used WSL

Comment: I just ran it in CMD and got ```The system cannot find the path specified.
The [/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ecom/public/storage] link has been connected to [/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ecom/storage/app/public].
The links have been created.```